# Retrofit 2 Multipart file upload Error

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipart

Trying to upload profile picture through api call using Retrofit 2 and rxjava. Response is always gives me error which is 422 Unprocessable Entity. Giving my code and need suggestion to overcome this.

```
@Multipart
@POST("api/update-profile-picture")
Observable<ProfilePicture> updateProfilePicture(
        @Header("Authorization") String accessToken,
        @Part("profile_picture") RequestBody profile_picture
);


// calling presenter method to update profile picture
public void updateProfilePictureImage(File file){
    getMvpView().showProgress();

    RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    //MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("profile_picture", file.getName(), reqFile);

    oyeBuddyService.updateProfilePicture("Bearer" + " " + mPrefs.getOyeUserAccessToken(), reqFile)
            .subscribeOn(mNewThread)
            .observeOn(mMainThread)
            .subscribe(new Observer<ProfilePicture>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    getMvpView().hideProgress();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    getMvpView().hideProgress();
                    Log.e("error: ",e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ProfilePicture profilePicture) {
                    Log.e("response: ", profilePicture.toString());
                    getMvpView().onProfilePictureUpdated(profilePicture.profile_picture_url);
                }
            });
}
```

Response --->

```
RetrofitModule: Received response for http://174.138.64.95/api/update-profile-picture in 4540.6ms
                                                                                 Date: Wed, 04 Oct 2017 10:30:53 GMT
                                                                                 Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
                                                                                 Vary: Authorization
                                                                                 Cache-Control: no-cache, private
                                                                                 X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
                                                                                 X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
                                                                                 Content-Length: 99
                                                                                 Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
                                                                                 Connection: Keep-Alive
                                                                                 Content-Type: application/json

E/error:: HTTP 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

Comment: This may help u https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/696

Comment: @Anil thanks. It didn't help

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `@Part MultipartBody.Part profile_picture` instead of RequestBody to Retrofit interface.

Comment: Multipart
    POST("api/update-profile-picture")
    Observable<ProfilePicture> updateProfilePicture(
            Header("Authorization") String accessToken,
            Part MultipartBody.Part profile_picture
    );

tried in both way. Same result.

Comment: How about using an exact mime type (without asterisk) and checking that your file name is correct? Can you use a request inspector (like Stetho) to see that the request is OK? Similar code works just fine for me.

Comment: Thats my point. I have used directly "multipart/form-data" but same response. I will check it via stetho and will let you know

Answer (score 0):

You need to add header like:

Accept = */*

For Example:

```
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {  
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        Request request = original.newBuilder()
            .header("Accept", "*/*")
            .method(original.method(), original.body())
            .build();

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly for which reason I have to add extra header?

Comment: @demo_Ashif In your request have multipart data so maybe server not recognize request type so.. pls add and try it.

Comment: Nope you are wrong because I have already added type and server knows about the data.